# How to create users with different dashboard layouts and privileges using RailsAdmin in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

We are trying to create different groups of users with restricted database
functionality using the railsAdmin plugin in Rails. Specifically, there is a
table in the database that indexes all personnel. We want to create two
levels of user accounts. "Admins" have access to all personnel. "Moderators"
have access to a subset of personnel only. Further, moderators should be
able to add personnel to the database, but they should be visible only to
that moderator and the admins. As an example, if user A is a moderator and
adds a person named "Dave,", we don't want Dave to be visible in the
dashboard for other moderators (e.g., B, C, etc). Similarly, if moderator B
adds a person, s/he should be visible only to moderator B. We are having
difficulty determining where in the code this type of functionality should
be added. Any pointers would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) with rails_admin?

There is a pretty good guide on authorisation using CanCan with rails_admin on their wiki:
https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Cancan

p.s. you might prefer to use [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) which is more actively maintained